# What happens if I connect a solar panel and an AC/DC PSU in series?

Tags: power-supply, solar-cell, atx

I'm thinking about connecting the DC12V output of an ATX PSU with a solar panel in series.
I want an always-on power source with as much power coming from the Sun as possible.

Comment: Boom ... and the magic smoke leaks out ...

Comment: Oh. And why exactly?

Comment: Photovoltaic cell is a diode, imposing current flow from external source (Your ATX PSU) quickly burn it.

Comment: Say  you have a load in parallel with the series connected PSU and panel. If the PSU is off and the panel is exposed to sunlight, the panel will output a voltage that forces current trough the PSU, resulting in a voltage drop that is negative relative to the voltage in normal operation and forcing current in weird paths within the PSU circuitry. Bad idea.

Comment: @jms Sounds reasonable. And if I connect them parallel?

Comment: Then the higher voltage one will backfeed the other (not good either). You can prevent that by adding diodes in series with the power sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they acted like ideal voltage sources, you could put them in series and they would additively combine their voltage (19V from the panel and 24V from the supply = 43V). However ideal voltage sources can supply infinite amounts of current, your supply and panel cannot do this. The main problem is the current, your panel has an IV curve, the more current you pull from it the less voltage you will get. They have circuits\IC's that optimize the power being pulled from the cell (solar MPPT tracker). You may be able to use a topology like this, you would have to keep the MPPT voltage right above the rail of the supply by tenths of volts and a topology like this would not be easy to get working.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFlJg9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this is a valuable answer! How can I calculate how much current will either the cell and the PSU give using this topology? Is it possible somehow to use every bit of power from the cell? Or the MPPT does that despite the PSU being there too?

Comment: I would suggest reading up on how MPPT's work (lots of studying), a simple explanation here is not going help you debug a system like this. A current limited DC/DC conveter would do the job, limit the current when the solar cell system is producing power. You could measure the current from the MPPT with current amp and then use that signal to change the current to the DC/DC converter (linear tech makes some current limited DC/DC's).